# Highcharts-X-Axis Text Direction

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, highcharts

Good day, am trying to use Highcharts Basic Column but need to change the x-axis text direction to look like the attached image. What property would I set please?

Thank you for your anticipated prompt response.

Comment: There is option http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.rotation